# How To Display Text In Result Of An MS Word ADDIN Field?

Tags: c#, plugins, ms-word, vsto

I am developing a word plug-in using vsto. I get to put some text, such as a record from a json fiel, in an MS Word ADDIN field, then display part of it in the result of that field.

Here is a sample. The code of an MS Word field like this:

```
{ ADDIN <name>NaslaN</name><title>programmer</title><address>blah blah...</address> }`.
```

And I want that field display it result in a word document like:

> (NalslaN, programmer).

Well, I can use the following code to add a field to document,Code:`field.Result.Text = "(NalslaN, programmer)"`. But I can't figure out how to set the result of that field to "(NalslaN, programmer)", it alwaysbe empty.

I try to use the following code to set the result of that field.Code:`Range myRange = myField.Result; myRange.Text="(NalslaN, programmer)"`. But the text inserted text appear to be a seperate section, it is not the result of that field, the latter always keeps empty.

Can anyone tell me the answer or give me some hint?

Comment: An `Addin` field has not have result or display capability. My recommendation would be to use a Custom XML Part to store this information in a document. Map it to a Content Control on the document surface in order to display information in an XML element in the document. (In this case, you'd need two content controls separated by a comma+space.)

Comment: That is ok.But i try to insert 100 fields,performance badly.I am trying edit xmldom to display the result of field.

Comment: I do not know whether I can do it by judging field showcodes to toggle display code range and result range or not.